# UE4 C++ Unrecognized type 'FMasterItem' - type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT or UENUM

Tags: c++, structure, unreal-engine4

I have an issue declaring the variable in the FCraftingRecipie struct. as line 19 throws the error Unrecognized type 'FMasterItem' - type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT or UENUM - MasterItem.h  - Line 19

The Master item needs to store an array of the FCraftingRecipie as this is a list of the items required and the amounts.

Here is a copy of the MasterItem Header File

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Engine/DataTable.h"
#include "MasterItem.generated.h"

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FCraftingRecipie : public FTableRowBase
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    FCraftingRecipie();

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        FMasterItem itemClass;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        int amount;
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FMasterItem : public FTableRowBase
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    FMasterItem();

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        FName itemID;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        FText name;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        FText description;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        UTexture2D* itemIcon;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        bool canBeUsed;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        FText useText;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        bool isStackable;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        float itemWeight;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        TArray<FCraftingRecipie> recipie;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        float price;

    bool operator==(const FMasterItem& OtherItem) const
    {
        if (itemID == OtherItem.itemID)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Clearly `C++`.  Removed `C` tag.

Comment: In normal C++, we can just add a **forward declaration** of FMasterItem to solve this, but UnrealBuildTool still cannot recognize UStruct (while UClass is OK)

Comment: Not related to the question, but it's spelled: "Recipe", not "Recipie"

Answer (score 1):

You declared a FMasterItem field (itemClass) line 19, in FCraftingRecipie. However, you only declare FMasterItem afterward in the same file. This doesn't work in C++, you need to define the class before it can be referenced someplace else in the same file (this is why the error is saying that the type is not recognized).

I would suggest moving the FCraftingRecipie declaration under FMasterItem. However FMasterItem also references FCraftingRecipie. What's you've created is a circular dependency, a situation where A needs to know B, but B needs to know A. These kind of decency can be resolved by using a reference/pointer rather than a value type field.